# _private directory doesn't get included in GitHub pages build for javadoc

Tags: java, github, github-actions, github-pages, javadoc

The directory **_private** and its contents don't get included in the GitHub pages build.
The **java doc** for the project has a **_private** directory, whose content don't end up in the GitHub pages build.
When a PR is merged, that the action automatically builds the develop branch and pushes the built site to the gh-pages branch, but I can't see the directory's content there.

Answer (score 0):

> the action automatically builds the develop branch and pushes the built site to the gh-pages branch

It depends which action.

For instance, [this action](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml/blob/main/action.yml) uses the [`JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action`](https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action) step, after generating the javadoc.

```yaml
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
  - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      java-version: ${{ inputs.java-version }}
      distribution: 'adopt'
  - name: Generate Javadoc
    run: mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.3.1:aggregate
    shell: bash
  - name: Deploy 
    uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.8
    with:
      token: ${{ inputs.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      branch: ${{ inputs.javadoc-branch }}
      clean: true
      folder: target/site/apidocs
      target-folder: ${{ inputs.target-folder }}
```

Comment: ```name: 'Build and deploy website'
description: 'Builds the latest version of the website and deploys it to gh-pages'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'```
https://github.com/fazer1929/wildfly-elytron/blob/develop/.github/actions/build-and-deploy-site/Dockerfile


Here is the link to the Dockerfile

and here is the link to the script that it runs
https://github.com/fazer1929/wildfly-elytron/blob/develop/.github/actions/build-and-deploy-site/entrypoint.sh

Comment: @fazer1929 OK. Can you try (for testing) my alternative approach using GitHub actions instead of a script doing directly git push?